# Get current user in WinRT

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012

I'm a C# developer and I'm used to the good old `Environment.CurrentUser`. Now I need exaclty that in my Windows 8 Metro app (html & js).

So how do I get it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.aspx).

There's also an example that uses this class, the [Account picture name sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Account-picture-name-sample-912baff1)
.